# 1 compilation, several outputs

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I'm a teacher and using PdfTeX to write my courses.
My question is the following : How can I compile my .teX file and generate into Pdf file : the course itself, and one or two excerpts (that I've chosen) of this same document.
Typically, I edit the whole course with annotations for myself throughout the whole document but I want to provide my students with portions of it only (AND without annotations)
Thank you

Addendum post comments: 
Let me a little be more specific :
Let's assume a document such as :

```
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}
        Big array
    \end{tabular}

\begin{note for self}
  here should be done ex 2 p75
\end{note for self}

bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

Then compilation. Nature of the wanted outputs (.pdf) :

1) Normal (with everything provided in the document) for my personal use.

2) The same document WITHOUT the "note for self". For students use.

3) If possible a third output with the array only. For other students to cut out and stick in their notebook. (in the code i used no made up code because I didn't know how to make a reference to it).

I hope my case is a little bit clearer now.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71559/8528) of mine could be adapted for this problem. I could expand on it, but how to expand the basic example there should be pretty clear.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5228/5764); [Write multiple PDFs with different options](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200719/5764)

Comment: I really thought there would be lost of questions like that, but I can't find that many, I'm probably not using the right search terms though. Generally an easy solution will use the idea of jon's answer. A bit more on switches/conditionals can be found in [LaTeX conditional expression](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5894/35864)) What I could find though are [Producing different versions of a document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22523/35864) and [How to create two PDFs from the same source](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123388/35864).

Comment: Also similar here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258687/generate-multiple-pdfs-for-different-document-versions-in-a-single-build

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to write hidden notes in a LaTeX file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/how-to-write-hidden-notes-in-a-latex-file)

Comment: Thank you all for your reactivity.
But indeed I browsed through the forum but didn't find what I need (it might be also a pb of tags...)
I've just modified my question and provided some sort of an example.

Answer (score 6):

[`multiaudience`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience) package could be an alternative to `comment` package. You will also need several compilations to get any pdf version unless you hide them inside a `makefile` or any other script system. But `multiaudience` provides advantatges in front of `comment` because you can *combine/discard* different audiences and not only select one of them.

Following you have a little example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multiaudience}

% Declare all possible audience groups
\SetNewAudience{teachers}
\SetNewAudience{students}
\SetNewAudience{public}

%You can decide the desired audience inside the document
%\DefCurrentAudience{public}

\begin{document}

% this array is always included
\begin{tabular}{c}
  All: First sentence seen by all audiences
\end{tabular}

% only for teachers
\begin{shownto}{teachers}
  Teachers: This text is seen only by teachers
\end{shownto}

% only for teachers and students
\begin{shownto}{public, students}
  Public,students: This text is seen by public and students but not teachers.
  \begin{shownto}{-,students}
  -students: But this one only by public
  \end{shownto}
\end{shownto}

% for all audiences except teachers
\begin{shownto}{-, teachers}
  -teachers: all except teachers.
\end{shownto}

\end{document}
```

Instead of fixing the audience inside the `.tex` file you can pass it as a compilation parameter:

```
pdlatex "\def\CurrentAudience{students}\input{your-tex-file}"
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the `comment` package like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

% Include custom environments before they are included/excluded
\specialcomment{teachersnote}{}{}
\specialcomment{notinsummary}{}{}

% Comment out as needed
\excludecomment{teachersnote}
\excludecomment{notinsummary}

\begin{document}

% this array is always included
\begin{tabular}{c}
  Big array
\end{tabular}

\begin{teachersnote}
  here should be done ex 2 p75
\end{teachersnote}

\begin{notinsummary}
  bla bla bla
\begin{teachersnote}
  this is a note inside a non-summary section.
\end{teachersnote}
\end{notinsummary}
\end{document}
```

The simplest way to create 3 pdfs in a platform independent way is probably to create 3 different files and use `\input` to put the body of your document in.

---

Example:

To compile (to put in a shell script/batch file, or done manually):

```
pdflatex teachersversion.tex
pdflatex studentsversion.tex
pdflatex studentssummaryversion.tex
```

preamble.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

% Include custom environments before they are included/excluded
\specialcomment{teachersnote}{}{}
\specialcomment{notinsummary}{}{}
```

body.tex:

```
\begin{document}

% this array is always included
\begin{tabular}{c}
  Big array
\end{tabular}

\begin{teachersnote}
  here should be done ex 2 p75
\end{teachersnote}

\begin{notinsummary}
  bla bla bla
\begin{teachersnote}
  this is a note inside a non-summary section.
\end{teachersnote}
\end{notinsummary}
\end{document}
```

teachersversion.tex:

```
\input{preamble}

% Comment out as needed
% \excludecomment{teachersnote}
% \excludecomment{notinsummary}

\input{body}
```

studentsversion.tex:

```
\input{preamble}

% Comment out as needed
\excludecomment{teachersnote}
% \excludecomment{notinsummary}

\input{body}
```

studentssummaryversion.tex:

```
\input{preamble}

% Comment out as needed
\excludecomment{teachersnote}
\excludecomment{notinsummary}

\input{body}
```

Comment: @JonathanPotier If you feel one of the answers here is what you're looking for, consider accepting one of them (clicking the faded arrow beneath the voting arrows)

Answer (score 2):

Some shameless self-promotion:
there is also my `commenting` package, available at

> https://github.com/bordaigorl/latex-commenting

You can declare multiple authors

```
\declareauthor{jon}{Jonathan}{blue}
```

and put comments in your text with various commands:

```
\comment[jon]{bla}% Inline comment
\annot[jon]{bla}% Margin comment
```

and others.

Then you can control what is shown by using either the `draft` class option or more fine grained macros like

```
\onlyauthors{jon}
```