# How to create hide-able environments

Tags: environments

I am relatively new to writing LaTeX packages.  I would like to create an environment so that anything contained in that environment can be ignored when producing output.  The desired behavior would be the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hide]{MyPackage}
\begin{document}
This should always show up.
\begin{Hidden}
This should show up unless the [hide] option is used.
\end{Hidden}
\end{document}
```

One possible use case: if I write a problem set for a class, I can write the solutions into the same document wrapped in the Hidden environment.  That way, I can compile with the [hide] option to produce the problem set for my students, and I can recompile without the [hide] option to produce the solution set.

Here's the code I currently use to accomplish this.  It was at some point borrowed from a package offering similar functionality, but unfortunately I can't remember the original package.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{MyPackage}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{MyPackage@hidden}
\setboolean{MyPackage@hidden}{false}
\DeclareOption{hide}{\setboolean{MyPackage@hidden}{true}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\newenvironment{Hidden}
    {\ifthenelse{\boolean{MyPackage@hidden}}
    {\setbox\z@\vbox\bgroup}{}}
    {\ifthenelse{\boolean{MyPackage@hidden}}{\egroup}{}}
```

This code has been working somewhat, but there are three main issues.  The first is that there are errors when I put figures inside the Hidden environment.  (This is a pretty common need when writing solutions to homework problems.)  The following code does not compile:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[hidden]{hideexample}

\begin{document}

This always shows up.

\begin{Hidden}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This shows up when not hidden, but causes an error when the [hide] option is used.}
\end{figure}
\end{Hidden}

\end{document}
```

The second issue is that I would like to implement multiple hide-able environments.  (Expanding on the homework use case, I might also want to create notes to the grader about how to assign partial credit.  So I would want to be able to independently hide/show the solutions and the grader comments.)  I have no idea how to adapt the code above to do this.  I never really understood what the code does, just that it (partially) worked.

The third "issue" isn't really a problem with the functionality, but another feature.  It would be really convenient if, instead of [hide]/[show] options, there was a [solutions] option (or something similar) so that compiling the document would produce both the homework set and the solution set at the same time.  (So, I would be working on HW.tex, and compiling would produce HW.pdf and HW_solutions.pdf at the same time.)  Is something like this possible?

Thanks in advance.

---

Follow-up: After modifying Werner's answer below, I'm using the code

```
\if@hidden
  \long\gdef\hide[#1]#2\ehide{\vspace{#1}}%
\else
  \long\gdef\hide[#1]#2\ehide{#2}%
\fi
```

This allows the following use:

```
\hide[4in]
%stuff
\ehide
```

This shows %stuff when I'm not using the global [hide] option.  When I am using the [hide] option, %stuff is hidden, and 4 inches of blank vertical space are shown instead (as a placeholder for %stuff).  The only issue is that this usage makes it look like [4in] is an optional argument.  Since \def requires an exact calling match, the argument is actually required.  How can I make this argument optional (i.e., with 0in as the default value)?

Comment: No need for `\hide[#1]#2\ehide` in the definition, you can use `\hide#1#2\ehide` and use `\hide{4cm} .. \ehide` unless you really wanted that `[..]` in which case it's okey :)

Comment: [`multiaudience`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience) package allows to define environments that will be printed or not according a parameter. An example of use can be seen in [1 compilation, several outputs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266682/1952)

Comment: Looks similar to [conditionals - Hide custom environment content based on boolean - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/hide-custom-environment-content-based-on-boolean), not sure it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to hide fairly common document elements. For that I would suggest capturing the environment contents using [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{MyPackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{MyPackage}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\newif\if@hidden% \@hiddenfalse
\DeclareOption{hide}{\global\@hiddentrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\NewEnviron{Hidden}
  {\if@hidden\else\BODY\fi}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[hide]{MyPackage}

\begin{document}

This should always show up.
\begin{Hidden}
This should show up unless the [hide] option is used.
\end{Hidden}

\end{document}
```

I've used basic TeX conditionals rather than [`xifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen), but that's up to you. See [Why is the `ifthen` package obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/5764).

---

If you wish to hide content using an abbreviated form, you'll have to specify it as such in a verbatim way. That is, if you want `\hide` and `\ehide` to define your start- and end-clause for capturing content to hide/not, then you have to use them as-is. Here's an example that includes an optional argument to `\hide` so you can specify a vertical gap to be left under the `[hide]` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{MyPackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{MyPackage}
\newif\if@hidden% \@hiddenfalse
\DeclareOption{hide}{\global\@hiddentrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\gdef\hide{\@ifnextchar[\hide@{\hide@[]}}
\if@hidden
  \long\gdef\hide@[#1]#2\ehide{\ifx\relax#1\relax\else\par\rule{0pt}{#1}\fi}% Gobble content between \hide...\ehide
\else
  \long\gdef\hide@[#1]#2\ehide{#2}% Release content between \hide...\ehide (ignore [.]
\fi
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[hide]{MyPackage}

\begin{document}

This should always show up.
\hide[2in]
This should show up unless the [hide] option is used.
\ehide

This should also show up.
\hide
This should show up unless the [hide] option is used.
\ehide

This will show up.
\end{document}
```

Note that nesting in these cases won't work.

Comment: Or the comment package?

Comment: Thanks for this, and for pointing me towards the etoolbox package.  I was using ifthen because whatever guide to writing a package I was using suggested it.  I'm happy to learn other methods.

I don't suppose you know how to produce both the HW set and solution set with one compile?  I think it's a separate enough question that I accepted your answer already and I'll write a separate question.

Comment: I'm having a new strange problem using this method.  With many of the other environments I use frequently, I define shortcuts like \newcommand{\thm}{\begin{Theorem}} and \newcommand{\ethm}{\end{Theorem}}.  This saves a lot of typing, and it has always worked perfectly fined.  But when I did the same thing for the Hidden environment, I get an error 'LaTeX Error: \begin{Hidden} on input line 27 ended by \end{document}.'  Why does the \ehide shortcut not seem to work?

Comment: @user18452: It is a *requirement* for you to use the complete `\end{Hidden}` clause, as this is used by TeX as the end-marker for defining `\BODY`. If you want to use an alternative way of handling it, like `\bthm` and `\ethm`, then I can show you how to do that.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Is there a simple way to redefine the end-marker so that I can use \hide and \ehide?  It's not such a big deal to have to type out \begin{Hidden} and \end{Hidden} every time, except that all of the other environments defined in this package have shortcuts, so I'd rather the Hidden environment have the same behavior.  Thanks!

Comment: @user18452: I've added something to show you how you can use `\hide`...`\ehide`.

Comment: Sorry to pester you with follow-up questions, but I've added a bit to the original post.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @user18452: See my updated answer.

Comment: @Werner, is there a way to modify your solution so the space created by the hidden text is preserved? This way it can be readily used for a problem/answer environment.

Comment: @invictus: Try [this paste](http://pastebin.com/SkX4Hk1n). It's an approximation for what you want, but it may suffice. It assumes you'll be using the environment form `Hidden` and that the content will be set on its own as a "paragraph". It's set in a box (that has zero `\parindent`, hence mentioning it may only be an approximation) and the box is used as measurement for `\vspace`. One could add `\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}` as part of box construction, or use a stored value for `\parindent` that fits with the `\documentclass` to be more accurate; not sure whether that's needed.

Comment: @Werner works great!