# Display or hide stuff in a document

Tags: conditionals

I am using comments in LaTeX, which are defined in my document as:

```
\newcommand{\notecorr}[1]{\iftoggle{comments}{\todo[color=green]{{[}COR.{]} #1}{}}\linebreak}
```

I would like to add something like an `if-else statement` when `FALSE`, then all comments disappear from the document and if it `TRUE`, then the comments are displayed.

Any suggestions how to add this?

Comment: You can use [`comments`](http://ctan.org/pkg/comments) or [`multiaudience`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience) packages. An example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266117/1-compilation-several-outputs/266682#266682

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\iftoggle` (from [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) actually has the following syntax:

```
\iftoggle{<toggle>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

It already provides an "if-else" statement. In your usage, the `<true>` clause executes

```
\todo[color=green]{{[}COR.{]} #1}{}
```

while the `<false>` clause executes

```
\linebreak
```

So, a proper grouping of elements within your macro should allow you to leave the `<false>` part completely blank `{}`.

Comment: So for example my command would look like: `\iftoggle{ <true> }{ \todo[color=green]{{[}COR.{]} #1}{} }{ \linebreak }`. Is this right?

Comment: @Kare: Well, this would put `\linebreak` as the `<false>` clause still (just like before). If you want nothing to happen when `\togglefalse{comments}`, then you'd need something like `\iftoggle{comments}{\todo[color=green]{{[}COR.{]} #1}{}\linebreak}{}`.