# Compile same content with different preambles

Tags: compiling, preamble

I've written notes for my students and I want to create different versions of them: a short one, to print, and a long one, to distribute them through internet. So for the same content, and I want to compile it twice with different behaviour.

Here is a MWE of what I do:

- the content of chapter 1 is `content1.tex`

```
\begin{document}

This is some text.

\important{This is very important.}

\remark{This is a remark.}

\end{document}
```

- the content of chapter 2 is `content2.tex`

```
\begin{document}

\important{This is very very very important.}

\remark{This is a useless remark.}

This is some text

\end{document}
```

- the file `full_version.tex` contains a first set of `\newcommand`s:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newcommand{\important}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\remark}[1]{\textit{Remark: #1}}
```

- the file `short_version.tex` contains a second set of `\newcommand`s:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newcommand{\important}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\remark}[1]{}
```

My solution is the following: to compile the `content1` with the `full_version` preamble, I write this command on Linux shell:

```
 cat full_version.tex content1.tex | latex
```

It works, but is not very satisfactory (many strange messages); and Linux-shell dependant.

Are there better way to achieve this? Perhaps with precompiled preambles?

Comment: you don't need to use cat just put `\input{content}` into your two top level files.

Comment: Okay, but my top level files will be used for many contents, since my notes are divided in many chapters. So I need a method that can combine any top level file with any content file.

Comment: I modified the question to make it clearer.

Comment: you can compile with `latex \input{full_version.tex}\input{content1.tex}`

Comment: You could try with [`multiaudience`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience) package. This is an example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266682/1952

Comment: @Ignasi Okay that seems interesting, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile using something like:

```
latex -jobname="full_chapter1" "\input{full_version}\input{chapter1}"
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, and good hint the `jobname` to rename output.